# How to disable/enable interrupts on a stm32f107 chip?

Tags: c, gcc, assembly, embedded, iar

I have an ARM stm32f107 chip. I'm porting a project from IAR to GCC

IAR provides the following functions to enable and disable interrupts:

```
#define __disable_interrupt() ...
#define __enable_interrupt() ...
```

How do I enable / disable interrupt for my chip using GCC?

Comment: the simplest way to figure this out is to disassemble the IAR generated code, from there you will see what is really going on and you can then write portable code instead of compiler specific code.  (the answers are in the architectural reference manual and/or the technical reference manual for the architecture and core, found at infocenter.arm.com)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't answer for ARM but the same function in Coldfire boils down to setting/clearing the Interrupt Priority Level masking register in the CPU. Setting it to the highest number disables/ignores all but non-maskable, setting it to 0 enables all (YMMV).

Worth noting that it's handy to read-back the value when "disabling" and restore when "enabling" to ensure that stacked interrupts don't break each other:

```
ipl = DisableInts(); // Remember what the IPL was
<"Risky" code happens here>
EnableInts(ipl); // Restore value
```

This is useful when twiddling interrupt masks, which may cause spurious interrupts, or doing stuff that shouldn't be interrupted.

Functions come out as:

```
uint8 DisableInts(void)
{
    return(asm_set_ipl(7));
}

uint8 EnableInts(uint8 ipl)
{
    return(asm_set_ipl(ipl));
}
```

Both of which map to this asm:

```
asm_set_ipl:
_asm_set_ipl:
/* Modified for CW7.2! */
    link    A6,#-8
    movem.l D6-D7,(SP)

    move.l  D0,D6           /* save argument                 */

    move.w  SR,D7           /* current sr                    */

    move.l  D7,D0           /* prepare return value          */
    andi.l  #0x0700,D0      /* mask out IPL                  */
    lsr.l   #8,D0           /* IPL                           */

    andi.l  #0x07,D6        /* least significant three bits  */
    lsl.l   #8,D6           /* move over to make mask        */

    andi.l  #0x0000F8FF,D7  /* zero out current IPL          */
    or.l    D6,D7           /* place new IPL in sr           */
    move.w  D7,SR

    movem.l (SP),D6-D7
    //lea     8(SP),SP
    unlk    A6
    rts
```

Comment: Just to add - the above is a global interrupt enable/disable. To enable/disable an individual interrupt you need to RTFM for the cpu's interrupt registers and twiddle the correct bits - again, in CF it means setting a bit in the interrupt mask register to disable that source. It's a good idea to use the code above around the twiddling operation to prevent spurious interrupts during the operation.

Answer (score 5):

When developing for the STM32, [RM0008](http://www.st.com/internet/com/TECHNICAL_RESOURCES/TECHNICAL_LITERATURE/REFERENCE_MANUAL/CD00171190.pdf) is your best friend. From Section 10.2.4 on page 199:

> To generate the interrupt, the interrupt line should be configured and
>   enabled. This is done  by programming the two trigger registers with
>   the desired edge detection and by enabling  the interrupt request by
>   writing a ‘1’ to the corresponding bit in the interrupt mask register.

So you need to set the appropriate mask bits in the appropriate registers. For external interrupts, that's the EXTI_IMR and EXTI_EMR registers. There are many others.

[image: EXTI registers]

Answer (score 0):

The [ARM Documentation](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dai0321a/BIHBFEIB.html) says that `_enable_irq();` compiles to “CPSIE I” that means Clear All Masks. On the other hand `_disable_irq();` compiles to Set  Mask.